# result of correlation function in r

Tags: r, correlation, confusion-matrix

I would like to ask if the matrix that is returned from the R cor() function applied on a dataset, is considered a confusion matrix. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it is not a confusion matrix.

Please have a look at the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/cor.html)

[This](http://www.inside-r.org/node/86995) is how the confusion matrix is created in R.